# How can I get value of Home Page Standard Components like Custom Links,Messages and Alerts on Custom VisualForce Page?

Tags: visualforce, home-page-component

I want to add values of Home Page's Standard Components like Custom Links,Messages and Alerts on Custom VisualForce Page. Does anyone knows how can I do that? Does anyone knows where its values get stored? I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working out this problem.

[image]

Comment: Any answer for this question.It would be very helpful to me if you can share a solution for it